# Keep Volkswagen TDI or let VW buy it back?

Tags: vw, jetta, tdi

So I have one of the "diesel gate" VW TDI. Should I let VW buy it back and take out a new car loan or should I take the settlement amount and purchase some parts that any mechanic can fix if need be?

Comment: Could you add some details about the buy back and settlement (or link to it) that would help folks help you evaluate the options.